# How can I get DNS records for a domain in python?

Tags: python, dns

How do I get the DNS records for a zone in python?  I'm looking for data similar to the output of `dig`.

Answer (score 10):

A simple example from https://c0deman.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/find-nameservers-of-domain-name-python/:

```
import dns.resolver
 
domain = 'google.com'
answers = dns.resolver.resolve(domain,'NS')
for server in answers:
    print(server.target)
```

Comment: NoAnswer: The DNS response does not contain an answer to the question: stream.binance.com. IN NS

Answer (score 5):

You can use python's socket library to get the DNS records from ip address or domain name

```
import socket

# if ip address is available
DNS_record = socket.gethostbyaddr("66.249.65.189")

# if domain name is available
DNS_record = socket.gethostbyname("google.com")
```

For more info:

- [`socket.gethostbyaddr()`](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr)
- [`socket.gethostbyname()`](https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname)

Comment: This doesn't get DNS records, but resolves a name or IP address to a single record.  This is suitable for getting a single address to connect to, but is too high level for retrieving DNS records.

Answer (score 3):

`dns.resolver.query` is deprecated now, it is recommended to use `dns.resolver.resolve`:

```
# python3 -m pip install dnspython

import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.resolve("google.com", 'NS')
for server in answers:
    print(server.target)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your other option is [pydns](http://pydns.sourceforge.net/) but the last release is as of 2008 so dnspython is probably a better bet (I only mention this in case dnspython doesn't float your boat).